# Is there any efficient way to to make a mask on each cell of a grid rather than using a loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a catalog of the sky coordinates (for example  for 12 million galaxies), ra, dec (perpendicular to the line of sight) and redshift (along the line of sight) and I made a grid on the sky and then I compute different physical properties in each cell of this grid.

For the pixelization perpendicular to the line of sight I used [healpy](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I got an array named `res`, in which it contains the indices of each cell perpendicular to the line of sight. For example `ra[res[1]]` gives me the ra of all the galaxies in the perpendicular cell number 1.

I also binned the distance along the line of sight (`chi`) as follows:

```
bins = np.linspace(np.min(chi),np.max(chi),nzbin)
hist, edges = np.histogram(chi, bins=bins)
```

I want to create a large mask boolian array that contains all the components of my catalog in each cell, then later I use it to compute different properties in each cell. I made it as follows, by sing two loops:

```
mask_list = []
for i in range(nzbin-1):
    for j in range(len(res)):
        mask = (np.min(ra[res[j]]) <= ra ) & ( ra <= np.max(ra[res[j]])) & (np.min(dec[res[j]]) <= dec) & (dec <= np.max(dec[res[j]])) & (chi >= edges[i]) & (chi < edges[i+1]) 
        mask_list += [mask]
mask_grid = np.vstack(mask_list)
```

And then later to compute different properties in each cell I call my `mask_grid` as follows:

```
cell = len(res)*len(bin_centers)
for i in range(cell):
    ra_masked = ra[mask_grid[i]]
```

For a small values of `nzbins` (for instance 500), this works well, but when I increase it to 5000 I do have memory issues.

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to create this `mask_grid`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

and you could have your mask with:

```py
mask = np.where(your_condition)[0]
```

Comment: If you need a more precise answer, can you post a way to have a similar structure than your data cause it is a bit unclear to me. 
You have a healpix with float values associated to cell indexes? So what's the shape of the resulting data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist, but you can use convolution on a 2d array instead of doing a for loop on each elements. It's like applying a mask to it. I can't really give you a clear example. But that's the idea.